# python pass multiple arguments to many functions

Tags: python

I can do:

```
myfun(a=1, b=2,c=3,d=4)
myfun(a=2, b=2,c=3,d=4)
myfun(a=1000, b=2,c=3,d=4)
```

But is there a way to store `b,c,d` and pass just one object to the function? Changing the value to any of `b,c,d` is costly, since I need to change it in many places.

I want something like this pseudocode:

```
args = (b=2, c=3, d=4)
myfun(a=1, **args)
```

Comment: Almost! Make `args` a dict: `{'b': 2, ...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudocode is close to be true:

```py
args = dict(b=2, c=3, d=4)
myfun(a=1, **args)
```